# Latex to ODF/DOC using mk4ht oolatex failing on equation arrays

Tags: math-mode, conversion, mathml

Title says it all.

**Anyone got any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Is this a fundamental fault with oolatex conversion? Is there an alternative math format I can use?**

Same math builds fine in latex and pdflatex.

Example input (test.tex)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
              x = \begin{array}{cc} 
                1, & \mbox{for } 0.5\leq p \leq 1 \\
                0, & \mbox{for } 0\leq p \le 0.5 \\     
              \end{array}

\end{equation}    
\end{document}
```

Execute:

```
mk4ht oolatex test.tex
```

Error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...\a:mathml columnlines="\columnlines 
                                                  " \a:mathml equalcolumns="...
l.5                 1
                     , & \mbox{for } 0.5\leq p \leq 1 \\
?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known [bug](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex4ht/2009q4/000015.html). Try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\columnlines\empty
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
              x = \begin{array}{cc} 
                1, & \mbox{for } 0.5\leq p \leq 1 \\
                0, & \mbox{for } 0\leq p \le 0.5 \\     
              \end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works for the test case, but unfortunately not for the global case. Must be a package conflict, but thank you for your answer!